# Can't append text to a JTextArea from another class

Tags: java, swing, reference, jtextarea

Found a similar topic on here but the solutions provided didn't work (or I'm just not seeing it). Here's my code reduced to the minimum:

Here's the class I want to call the print method from:

```
{
    HumanInterface gui = new HumanInterface();
    gui.init();
    gui.printToArea("from Main Class");
}
```

and here's the HumanInterface class which extends JFrame
    {

```
JTextArea area = createArea();

public void init() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
{
    HumanInterface gst = new HumanInterface();
    gst.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gst.pack();
    gst.setVisible(true);

    printToArea("print from HumanInterface class");
}

public HumanInterface() throws InvocationTargetException,
        InterruptedException
{
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));

    container.add(new JScrollPane(area));
}

public void printToArea(String string)
{
    try
    {
        updateArea(area, string);
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JTextArea createArea()
{
    final JTextArea area;
    area = new JTextArea();
    area.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    return area;
}

private void updateTextArea(final JTextArea textArea, final String string)
        throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            textArea.append(string);
        }
    });

}
```

When I call printToArea(...) from anywhere else than from within the HumanInterface class, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you set JTextArea in `createArea()` to final?

Comment: Moreover, in `printToArea()` what is the `updateArea(area, string)` function?? You have `updateTextArea(area, string)` defined

Comment: I was about to point that out... you need to call the updateTextArea function inside your printToArea method instead of the nonexisting updateArea you are using now. Still not working after that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI you see is not the GUI you "want" to see, it's a second ;-)

In your `init()` function you create a second `HumanInterface`:

```
HumanInterface gst = new HumanInterface();
gst.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gst.pack();
gst.setVisible(true);
```

I think you probably want that (not tested):

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.pack();
this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Didn't even notice that. But ye the correct answer!

Comment: Thanks so much, this was driving me nuts. Silly me!